# Prioritize One Network Share Over Another And/Or Cap Network Share Traffic? (Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise)

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, server-message-block, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, cifs

One of my fileservers is a hyper v VM running Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise.  The NIC in the VM maps to a 1 GB NIC on the host that is dedicated just to this VM.

I have two shares on the file server.  One is very important and used by a few users.  The other is less important but used by many users.

The issue I'm having:

When a ton of users are accessing the unimportant share, it can choke out requests to the important share.

What I'd like to do:

I'd like to some prioritize requests for for file on the more important share, or even dedicate a portion of the NIC's bandwidth just to requests for files on that share.   Is there any way to do that?  Alternately, can I add another NIC and specify that all traffic to one share goes over one NIC and traffic to the other share goes over the other?

Comment: do you have switches that will do qos?